Why Player interface doesn't have setPauseAtEndOfMediaItems method of ExoPlayer implementation?
I use MediaSession and MediaController and i want to add a button to enable/disable pause at end of media items.
ExoPlayer has setPauseAtEndOfMediaItems method but it's not present in his interface Player retrieved from MediaController
how can i do that?

if ExoPlayer do not provide such thing , here's an alternative : setup an listener of onMediaMetadataChanged inside that check player.hasNextMediaItem() if false when video / audio ends ( Setup listener for onPlaybackStateChanged ) (Player.STATE_ENDED) and disable pause accordingly

If you want to stop playing at the end of the media there is a repeatMode properties REPEAT_MODE_OFF.
If you use playlist be careful as REPEAT_MODE_OFF will still move to next mediaItem is there is one.
If you wish to detect when you move to the next item, you can use onMediaItemTransition
Player.addListener(object: Player.Listener {
    override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
        super.onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem, reason)
        //check if your settings is enable and if so just pause the player
    }
})


yes, i have  a playlist and want a toggle to enable/disable move to next media item

the problem is that current item has already changed and all player info are already poiting to next item
